# Touch event on an pin annotation on a MKMapView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, annotations

i've been trying to display a view controller when I tap on a pin annotation of my map View: The first time I used a container view and change his position in order to "hide" it. Than, when I tap on an annotation I used the `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView){}` to move the position of the view controller that I want to display to the center of my screen. 
Unfortunately I wasn't able to close the view controller because when I tried to use the function `dismissViewController`.... It dismiss all the view controllers of my app. 
So I trie to move the position of the view controller that I want to display a when the user touch the close button, it works only one time, if I tap on an other annotation, the view controller won't show up.
I can't do with segue because the annotation aren't shown in the main.storyboard
To resume, my question is:  How can I display a second View Controller by touching an annotation on my map.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the function `performseguewithidentifier` on following method:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view:  MKAnnotationView){
    // do your things here
}
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: This answer saved me at least couple of hours. Thanks.